# PyQt5 loading ui file directly vs converting ui file to py file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, guid, pyside2

I am just starting with PyQT5 and it appears to me that there are two ways when working with QT designer to use the ui files. One is to load it directly using the uic.loadui() and the other is to use pyuic5.exe to convert the ui file to a py file. My question is which is more efficient? And when do you opt for one over the other?

Comment: The loadui method is much less efficient because the xml has to be parsed and the ui code has to re-generated every time your application is run; whereas with pyuic this is all done only once. The other question is merely a matter of personal opinion, since both methods produce identical results.

Comment: @ekhumoro but why would there be two methods that do the exact same thing but one is less efficient than the other. I guess i can see the loadui method being less efficient because, like you said, it has to generate the code and then execute it every time whereas a py file only has to execute the code stored inside it. I just thought maybe there was something to the loadui method that i didn’t know. Is it possibly done for prototyping your ideas fast, because you do not have to keep generating code every time you edit your GUI?

Comment: There are two methods for the simple reason that generating ***anything*** dynamically always has an extra runtime cost. If you don't want to pay that cost, you can use pyuic. OTOH, if you want to avoid the extra pre-compilation step and don't mind paying the runtime cost, you can use loadui. It's just a matter of personal taste as to which particular cost you prefer to pay.